# How can I securely implement a notification system using socket?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sockets, redis, notifications

I am currently working on a web application using the MEAN stack. It has a social aspect to it so I want to be able to push notifications to users.

The way I do it now is when something happens that should be a notification it gets stored in a mongo database with an unread flag. Each client will send a get request to the server every 30 second and will receive every notification marked as unread, and will then mark it as read.

I want to switch to using a message queue and sockets so less network resources will be used, and also provide the user with a real-time experience. I've thought about using redis and its pubsub structure but I can't seem to figure out how to do this securely. If I push out notifications to the affected users, won't it be easy for someone malicious to subscribe to somebody else's channel and receive notifications not meant for them? Am I missing something or is it just the wrong approach for such a system?

Edit: Figure I update with the solution I went with if anyone else reading this is having the same problem.

Instead of using rabbitmq, as the answer suggested, I figured that a much more easy and elegant solution is to just use socket.io. When new sockets connects to the server I save a mapping from the userID to the socketId in a redis in-memory DB. (After I've validated their token) That way, if I need to push a notification to a user I just look up the socketId in the redis DB, and then send it to the correct socket.
<s>This way I don't need any security beyond that as socketIDs are unguessable, and the message is only sent across the single socket that belongs to the given user.</s>

This way it will only get sent through the connection of the given socket, as socketIDs are only used server side to keep track of all the connection. This means no one else can "listen" using someone else's socketID.

Comment: I beg to differ. Security through obscurity is considered outdated some 130 years. There is a reason why authentication and authorization are considered best practices: you make positively sure that a communication partner (subject) actually is who he claims to be and you check wether this specific subject is authorized to execute the requested action on a ressource. With just some communication channel hard to guess, you can never be halfway sure who sees your data.

Comment: I totally agree about the whole "security through obscurity" thing not being good enough. I don't know why I emphasized socketIDs being unguessable. As I understood it, using socket.io, there is no way for a client to "subscribe" to another socket id. It is just an internal ID on the server side to keep track of the individual sockets.

Comment: Thanks for the comment though, I will change my answer so that it is more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use RabbitMQ for this. Also authentication is there. Please go through following link and try.

https://www.rabbitmq.com/access-control.html

also, you can apply authentication in existing structure using subscription auth tokens with all subscribed users only.
even redis has its security with topics. Please have a look in link below

https://redis.io/topics/security

Comment: RabbitMQ seems to be the solution I was looking for. I will try implementing it in the application. Thank you!

Comment: it will provide all solutions.. realtime, secure and subscription.

Comment: On which planet is a messge queue realtime? Even with subscription, we are talking of near time, since the only guarantee a subscription gives you is that you are notified as soon as a message becomes *available*, which may or may not be near the time the message was sent.